# comparar dados do Sql com dois Foreach

Tags: php, sql-server, foreach

Estou buscando dados de duas tabelas as quais tem uma coluna igual, que se chama a coluna prefixo.

Tentei montar um foreach dentro do outro foreach com os dados das duas tabelas e comparando os valores pra quando forem iguais, ou seja o prefixo estivesse na duas tabelas alterasse a cor do button para verde, caso o prefixo(valor) esteja apenas em uma tabela coloque a cor vermelha, faço isso junto com a criação do button através do PHP.

```
 <?php
       foreach($produtos as $produto) {
   ?>

    <section class="abastecimento">
    <button class="pack detail btn" <?php         

                foreach($abastecimentos as $abastecimento) {

                    if ($abastecimento['prefixo'] == $produto['prefixo']) {
                       echo "style='background-color:green'";  
                    }else{
                        echo "style='background-color:red'";                        
                    }
                }     

            ?>  id="detail"><?php echo trim($produto['prefixo']);   ?>      

    </button>


    </section>


   <?php
       }
   ?>
```

O primeiro prefixo vem com a cor verde, já o segundo que também esta nas duas tabelas não pinta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que está fazendo vai dar errado, porque o segundo foreach vai gerar vários atributos `style` no button devido ao fato de quando o `if` não for satisfeito, irá entrar no `else` e criar um `style` a cada volta no laço, causando erro no HTML.

Crie uma variável booleana e só insira o style com o botão em vermelho caso o `if` do segundo foreach não tenha sido satisfeito:

```
<?php
foreach($produtos as $produto) {
   $bool = false;
?>
<section class="abastecimento">
   <button class="pack detail btn" <?php         

      foreach($abastecimentos as $abastecimento) {

         if ($abastecimento['prefixo'] == $produto['prefixo']) {
            echo "style='background-color:green'";
            $bool = true; // altera a variável
            break; // para o laço porque já encontrou um igual
         }
      }     

      if(!$bool){
         echo "style='background-color:red'";                        
      }

?>  id="detail"><?php echo trim($produto['prefixo']);   ?>      
   </button>
</section>
<?php
}
?>
```